# How to I install Tensorflow I have problem

Tags: python, pip, installation

I'm currently trying to pip install tensorflow. But I get the following error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

What should I do?

Oh and by the way i tried installing it with the following command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

But i think i just made it even worse.

- Currently on Windows 10
  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to install a TensorFlow package for Mac OS. Try with a suitable package for Windows 10. For example if you have Python 3.6 and want the CPU-only version you could try the following:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

But it is recommended to install TensorFlow using a virtualenv as shown on the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).